# Display not specified when trying to open Firefox on a home server

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, firefox, fedora, xorg

I am a new linux user, and I am currently running ubuntu on my desktop. I installed fedora server on an old laptop of mine. I thought it would be a good project to be able to open firefox on the server using an ssh session and browse the internet on my host machine using my server as kind of a proxy.
**What I am doing:**

1. ssh into the server
2. type *firefox*
3. *Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified*
4. type *firefox --display=0:0*
5. *Error: cannot open display: 0:0*

**What I have read and done so far:**
I read many 10 year old questions on superuser and stack overflow with a similar problems but never close enough to mine that I think the solution will work, but I tried one solution. I modified the /etc/ssh/sshd_config so that X11Forwarding, and X11UseLocalhost, were set to yes and X11DisplayOffset 10.That is what was done on the server, and on the host I also enabled x11. I did ssh -X when connecting to the server and tried everything above with the same result.

**When I pass -vv to ssh**
*debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug2: channel 0: request x11-req confirm 1
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: channel 0: setting env LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug1: Remote: No xauth program; cannot forward X11.
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 100 id 0
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0*

Comment: try `ssh -X user@host` and then start firefox

Comment: I though I got the -X to work but now that I try it again it seems to have failed.X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
Web console: https://slayer-server:9090/ or https://192.168.161.122:9090/

Comment: you should set display to :0.10 (check X11DisplayOffset )

Comment: OK. How did you know? you say check 11 display offset, but what is the first parameter before the colon? I'm assuming the :10 is because display offset is set to 10

Comment: Right, it must be `:10.0` :)

Comment: Progress is being made, when *firefox --display = 10:0* nothing happens. No error message and no return to the directory. Do you why this is happening? Edit it jsut delayed in telling me that that the display cannot be opened

Comment: Did you exec on source host `xhost +`?

Comment: Try running "ssh -X -vv user@host". The "-vv" will cause ssh to print debugging output while it's running. Then [edit] your question to show the exact ssh command that you ran and the debugging output. That should clarify what is happening when you try to use X forwarding.

Comment: Also, it shouldn't be necessary to set DISPLAY on the remote host when forwarding X. If the ssh session is forwarding X, then DISPLAY will be set to the correct value already. If you have to set DISPLAY on the remote host, then forwarding X through ssh isn't likely to work.

Comment: Try even with `ssh -Y user@host`. After with something as simple as `xlogo`. Then pass to `firefox` options. Just to avoid problem in passing options to firefox. BTW [edit] your post adding the system versions on the 2 computers.